# Premiere Pro: reducing/eliminating whiteboard specular glare

Tags: premiere

What are the most efficient and high-quality methods you would recommend for reducing/eliminating the three areas of whiteboard specular glare in this video? The spot near my head might be particularly challenging since my head moves into and out of that area during the video.

Video:

Answer (score 2):

Add a lumetri colour effect to it. Then go to the curves. Click on the line quite near the top. Then click in the middle Then go right to the top and drag it down to reduce the brightness of the highlight. Then just experiment with the curves. This should help remove the glare because it makes it less bright.

[image: Something like this]

Something like this